How to handle outside click in react ts
I'm using react typescript for the first time, and I implemented outside click event. I'm running into a problem where whenever i click on the active or currently selected component, it seems to trigger the onclick and outside click event.
Attached here i the GIF to better understand my problem.

when the selected component is clicked, it set as active, and when i click it again it seems like it triggers the outside click then trigger the click event.
here is my code implementation.
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import {
    Menubar,
    MenubarContent,
    MenubarItem,
    MenubarMenu,
    MenubarTrigger,
} from "@/components/ui/menubar";
import { MapPin, MoreVertical, PinOff } from "lucide-react";
import { HtmlHTMLAttributes, useState } from "react";
import OutsideClick from "outsideclick-react";
import { Props } from "@/utilities/navigation_props";

interface DocumentCardProps extends Props, HtmlHTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement> {
data: DateType,
onSelectActive: (id: number|null) => void,
}

type DateType = {
    id: number
}

const DocumentCard = ({
    data,
    active,
    onSelectActive,
    ...props
}: DocumentCardProps) => {

return (
    <OutsideClick
        onOutsideClick={() => {
            onSelectActive(null)
            console.log(active)
        }}
        ignoreElement={[".menubarEl"]}
        className="pointer-events-none"
        onClick={(e) => {
            e.stopPropagation()

            onSelectActive(data.id)
        }}
    >
        <div
            {...props}
            
            className={`h-56 p-2 flex flex-col rounded-xl cursor-default pointer-events-auto
            ${active == data.id ? "dark:bg-green-400/50 bg-green-400/50" : "hover:bg-tertiary"}`}
        >
            <div className="bg-tertiary grow rounded-lg overflow-hidden pointer-events-none">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/400" alt="" className="" />
            </div>
            <div className="shrink-0 py-2 text-sm font-medium px-0.5 flex items-center">
                <div className="grow">
                    <div className={`${active == data.id ? "dark:text-emerald-200" : ""}`}>
                        Document title
                    </div>
                    <div
                        className={`opacity-70 font-normal text-xs ${active == data.id ? "dark:text-emerald-300" : ""
                            }`}
                    >
                        Document{">"}path{">"}name
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <Menubar className="!border-none !bg-transparent !p-0">
                        <MenubarMenu>
                            <MenubarTrigger className="!px-0 focus:!bg-transparent data-[state=open]:!bg-transparent !p-0 !rounded-full ring-1">
                                <Button
                                    asChild
                                    variant={"ghost"}
                                    size={"iconxs"}
                                    className={`hover:dark:border-white/10 !rounded-full border hover:border-gray-300/60 dark:hover:bg-white/5 border-transparent`}
                                >
                                    <div>
                                        <MoreVertical className="h-4 w-4" />
                                    </div>
                                </Button>
                            </MenubarTrigger>
                            <MenubarContent className="ring-1 ring-inset menubarEl" align="end" alignOffset={20} sideOffset={-15}>
                                <MenubarItem>
                                    <PinOff className="w-5 h-5" strokeWidth={1.7} />
                                    <div className="ml-3">Unpin</div>
                                </MenubarItem>
                                <MenubarItem>
                                    <MapPin className="w-5 h-5" strokeWidth={1.7} />
                                    <div className="ml-3">Track</div>
                 

               </MenubarItem>
                                </MenubarContent>
                            </MenubarMenu>
                        </Menubar>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </OutsideClick>
    );
};

function Pinned() {
    const [active, setActive] = useState<number|null>(null)

const documents = [
    { id: 1 },
    { id: 2 },
    { id: 3 },
    { id: 4 },
    { id: 5 },
    { id: 6 },
    { id: 7 },
];

return (
    <div className="grid grid-cols-[repeat(auto-fill,minmax(17rem,1fr))] gap-1">
        {documents.map((item, index) => (
            <DocumentCard
                key={index}
                data={item}
                active={active}
                onSelectActive={(id) => {
                    setActive(id)
                }}
            />
        ))}
    </div>
);
}

export default Pinned;

I'm using outsideclick-react, and shadcn for the popover

I'm not too familiar with the OutsideClick library but it seems like the onClick handler is doing what it should, if you're clicking on that div.  Maybe  is meant to function like a wrapper, and you should put your onClick on the immediate child div, the one containing {...props}?

thank you for that but, it's still the same.

After implementing various ways for the problem, I came up with a solution by implementing the outsideclick on the parent component. I noticed that when i click outside the DocumentCard component, other DocumentCard components triggers an outsideclick which causes the problem. This was the revision i made:
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import {
    Menubar,
    MenubarContent,
    MenubarItem,
    MenubarMenu,
    MenubarTrigger,
} from "@/components/ui/menubar";
import { MapPin, MoreVertical, PinOff } from "lucide-react";
import { HtmlHTMLAttributes, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import OutsideClick from "outsideclick-react";
import { Props } from "@/utilities/navigation_props";

interface DocumentCardProps extends Props, HtmlHTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement> {
    data: DateType;
    onSelectActive: (id: number | null) => void;
    onClickMenu: () => void;
}

type DateType = {
    id: number;
};

const DocumentCard = ({
    data,
    active,
    onClickMenu,
    onSelectActive,
    ...props
}: DocumentCardProps) => {
    return (
        <div
            {...props}
            onClick={() => {
                onSelectActive(data.id);
            }}
            className={`h-56 p-2 flex flex-col rounded-xl cursor-default
                ${active == data.id
                    ? "dark:bg-green-400/50 bg-green-400/50"
                    : "hover:bg-tertiary"
                }`}
        >
            <div className="bg-tertiary grow rounded-lg overflow-hidden pointer-events-none">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/400" alt="" className="" />
            </div>
            <div className="shrink-0 py-2 text-sm font-medium px-0.5 flex items-center">
                <div className="grow">
                    <div
                        className={`${active == data.id ? "dark:text-emerald-200" : ""}`}
                    >
                        Document title
                    </div>
                    <div
                        className={`opacity-70 font-normal text-xs ${active == data.id ? "dark:text-emerald-300" : ""
                            }`}
                    >
                        Document{">"}path{">"}name
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id={"menubar-trigger-" + data.id}>
                    <Menubar className="!border-none !bg-transparent !p-0">
                        <MenubarMenu>
                            <MenubarTrigger
                                className="!px-0 focus:!bg-transparent data-[state=open]:!bg-transparent !p-0 !rounded-full"
                            >
                                <Button
                                    asChild
                                    variant={"ghost"}
                                    size={"iconxs"}
                                    className={`hover:dark:border-white/10 !rounded-full border hover:border-gray-300/60 dark:hover:bg-white/5 border-transparent`}
                                >
                                    <div>
                                        <MoreVertical className="h-4 w-4" />
                                    </div>
                                </Button>
                            </MenubarTrigger>
                            <MenubarContent
                                className=" menubarContainer"
                                align="end"
                                alignOffset={2}
                                sideOffset={2}
                            >
                                <MenubarItem className="menubarItem" onClick={() => onClickMenu()}>
                                    <PinOff className="w-5 h-5" strokeWidth={1.7} />
                                    <div className="ml-3">Unpin</div>
                                </MenubarItem>
                                <MenubarItem className="menubarItem" onClick={() => onClickMenu()}>
                                    <MapPin className="w-5 h-5" strokeWidth={1.7} />
                                    <div className="ml-3">Track</div>
                                </MenubarItem>
                            </MenubarContent>
                        </MenubarMenu>
                    </Menubar>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

function Pinned() {
    const [active, setActive] = useState<number | null>(null);

    const documents = [
        { id: 1 },
        { id: 2 },
        { id: 3 },
        { id: 4 },
        { id: 5 },
        { id: 6 },
        { id: 7 },
    ];

    useEffect(() => {
        const onOutsideClick = (e: MouseEvent) => {
            const element = document.getElementById("document-card-" + active);
            const menubar = document.querySelector(".menubarContainer");
            const menubarTrigger = document.getElementById(
                "menubar-tigger-" + active
            );
            const menubarItem = document.querySelector(".menubarItem");
            if (
                active &&
                !element?.contains(e.target as Node) &&
                !menubar?.contains(e.target as Node) &&
                !menubarItem?.contains(e.target as Node) &&
                !menubarTrigger?.contains(e.target as Node)
            ) {
                setActive(null);
            }
            console.log(e.target)
        };

        document.addEventListener("mousedown", onOutsideClick);

        return () => document.removeEventListener("mousedown", onOutsideClick);
    }, [active]);

    return (
        <div className="grid grid-cols-[repeat(auto-fill,minmax(17rem,1fr))] gap-1">
            {documents.map((item, index) => (
                <DocumentCard
                    key={index}
                    data={item}
                    active={active}
                    id={"document-card-" + item.id}
                    onSelectActive={(id) => {
                        setActive(id);
                    }}
                    onClickMenu={() => console.log('clickedMenu')}
                />
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Pinned;

So, the revised implementation is to put the outsideclick in the parent component ensuring that it only triggers once.

Stop event propagation to parent , use preventDefault()/stopPropagation()
